# Different Executables from the same source file?

Tags: c

Let's say I am creating a program and a makefile, and I want to be able to create three different executables with different names that all do different things, all with the same source file. Is this at all possible?

Comment: `argv[0]` can be used to select among multiple behaviors.

Comment: Or you can use preprocessor definitions, if you _really_ want three different executables (as opposed to one executable that cares how it's called). `gcc -Dmode=foo in.c -o foo`, `gcc -Dmode=bar in.c -o bar`, etc.

Comment: ...part of why we prefer questions about a _narrow, specific_ problem is that way we don't need to guess what your design constraints are. (Maybe you're installing each executable on a different embedded platform, and need to keep the binaries as small as possible -- in that case, you wouldn't want the multicall-binary approach; but this question says nothing about _why_ you're trying to do this, so we don't know which answers are or aren't appropriate for your use case).

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

Write a program that examines `argv[0]` to see what name it has been executed with and branches based on that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t length = strlen(argv[0]);
    
    if (3 <= length && strcmp(argv[0]+length-3, "foo") == 0)
        printf("This is the foo program.  It does foo things.\n");
    else if (3 <= length && strcmp(argv[0]+length-3, "bar") == 0)
        printf("This is the bar program.  It does bar things.\n");
    else
        printf("This is the default program.  It does default things.\n");
}
```

Compile the program and call the executable `x` or some other name.

Presuming you are using some version of Unix, link the file to more names:

```
ln x foo
ln x bar
```

Run the program with various names:

```
% ./x
This is the default program.  It does default things.
% ./foo
This is the foo program.  It does foo things.
% ./bar
This is the bar program.  It does bar things.
```

### Option 2

Use preprocessor symbols to build different programs. The source code can be:

```
#if   Option == 1
   #include "Program1.c"
#elif Option == 2
   #include "Program2.c"
#else
   #include "ProgramDefault.c"
#endif
```

The source code does not have to be in separate files. The above is only an example, and all of the source code could be in the file directly instead of included with `#include`.

With GCC and Clang, you can define a preprocessor symbol with `-DOption=value` on the command line to compile the program. The rules in a makefile can build the different programs by using different values in the compile command.